# Hilbert Spaces Self Study Guide

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am currently self-studying Hilbert Spaces. I have covered theories up to some extent and looking for some practice problems on the topic. Can someone please recommend me a good book with solved exercises for self studying Hilbert Spaces ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Check out "A Hilbert Space Problem Book" by Paul. R. Halmos. It has 250 problems on various topics in Hilbert space theory together with hints and solutions.